# How to search everything except something

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in the database.

1st table (`news`) of "All news released" with columns

```
NEWS_ID
```

2nd table (`plyrs_read`) of "players who read the news and which news" with columns

```
PLAYER_ID | NEWS_ID
```

3rd table (`players`) with of "All players on server". with columns

```
PLAYER_ID
```

I want to show a player all the news which the player hasn`t read. I have his id in $id.

Now I need help to get all those `NEWS_ID` in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03c0d/4)

```
select * from news n
where id not in(select pn.nid 
                from player_news pn
                where pn.pid = 1)
;
```

Results:

```
| ID |   TITLE |
----------------
|  1 | country |
```

Comment: @AkshayNaik please take a look into this and comment:) Given you have a relationship between news and player_news (player_read) table, that whichever news is not listed in that player_news table will be triggering the news table :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE news_id NOT IN(SELECT r.news_ID 
                     FROM plyrs_read r 
                     INNER JOIN players p ON r.Player_ID = p.Player_ID
                     WHERE p.player_ID = 'some id'
                       AND r.news_ID IS NOT NULL);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f05d/3)

Comment: I guess it could be even simpler :) since player_read has both player id and news id, we could connect the not existing news id for that plyaer to the news table.. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f05d/8

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NEWS_ID FROM table1
WHERE NEWS_ID NOT IN
    ( SELECT NEWS_ID FROM table2 WHERE PLAYER_ID = $id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.NEWS_ID FROM news n 
LEFT OUTER JOIN plyrs_read pr 
ON n.NEWS_ID = pr.NEWS_ID AND pr.PLAYER_ID = $id 
WHERE pr.NEWS_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Needless to say, you'll have to sanitize or properly escape the $id parameter.